# DD-WRT OpenVPN won't connect from remote location

Tags: openvpn, dd-wrt

I have DD-WRT v24-sp2 (12/22/14) std on my TPLink 3600 and I have configured my OpenVPN server. When I try to connect to my LAN, it works, but it is invisible from the internet.

Certificates are not expired, timeserver is set, ddwrt and windows firewall are off.

Previously, this configuration has absolutely worked from internet and LAN on this version of ddwrt. I reset, then vpn is not working.

Server configuration:

```
Start Type: WAN Up
Config as: Server
Server mode: Router (TUN) 
Network: 10.20.30.0
Netmask: 255.255.255.0
Port: 443
Tunnel Protocol: tcp
Encryption Cipher: aes-256-cbc
Hash Algorithm: sha1
Advanced Options: Disable
```

Vpn server status:

```
Server: CONNECTED SUCCESS
Local Address: 10.20.30.1
Remote Address:
```

Vpn client configuration file:

```
client
remote-cert-tls server
remote  443
dev tun2
proto tcp
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
float
comp-lzo
verb 3
ca ca.crt
cert kliens.crt
key kliens.key
cipher AES-256-CBC
```

Firewall rules:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD 1 --source 10.20.30.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -i br0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -i tun0 -o br0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.20.30.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -I INPUT 1 -i tun0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Vpn client while connecting from wan:

```
Mon Dec 14 01:36:04 2015 OpenVPN 2.3.8 x86_64-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [PKCS11] [IPv6] built on Aug  4 2015
Mon Dec 14 01:36:04 2015 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015, LZO 2.08
Mon Dec 14 01:36:04 2015 MANAGEMENT: TCP Socket listening on [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
Mon Dec 14 01:36:04 2015 Need hold release from management interface, waiting...
Mon Dec 14 01:36:04 2015 MANAGEMENT: Client connected from [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
Mon Dec 14 01:36:04 2015 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'state on'
Mon Dec 14 01:36:04 2015 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'log all on'
Mon Dec 14 01:36:04 2015 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold off'
Mon Dec 14 01:36:04 2015 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold release'
Mon Dec 14 01:36:04 2015 Socket Buffers: R=[8192->8192] S=[8192->8192]
Mon Dec 14 01:36:04 2015 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]100.66.138.135:443 [nonblock]
Mon Dec 14 01:36:04 2015 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1450053364,TCP_CONNECT,,,
Mon Dec 14 01:36:14 2015 TCP: connect to [AF_INET]100.66.138.135:443 failed, will try again in 5 seconds: A rendszer egy csatolt meghajtón lévõ könyvtárhoz próbált meg meghajtót csatolni.  
Mon Dec 14 01:36:19 2015 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1450053379,TCP_CONNECT,,,
```

Server log:

```
Jan  1 01:03:06 DD-WRT syslog.info syslogd started: BusyBox v1.22.1
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [    7.830000] eth0: link up (1000Mbps/Full duplex)
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.notice kernel: [    8.000000] SCSI subsystem initialized
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [    8.080000] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ar71xx-ehci
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [    8.250000] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [    8.300000] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0608
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [    8.300000] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [    8.310000] usb 1-1: Product: USB2.0 Hub
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [    8.350000] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [    8.360000] hub 1-1:1.0: 4 ports detected
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [   10.240000] device br0 entered promiscuous mode
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [   10.370000] device vlan1 entered promiscuous mode
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [   10.370000] device eth0 entered promiscuous mode
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [   10.380000] br0: port 1(vlan1) entered forwarding state
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [   10.390000] br0: port 1(vlan1) entered forwarding state
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [   10.390000] device br0 left promiscuous mode
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [   10.400000] device br0 entered promiscuous mode
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [   10.450000] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.err kernel: [   10.480000] cfg80211: Invalid regulatory domain detected:
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [   10.480000] cfg80211: Regulatory domain: 00
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [   10.480000] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [   10.490000] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [   10.500000] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [   10.510000] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [   10.520000] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [   10.530000] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [   10.540000] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [   10.560000] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [   10.580000] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [   10.590000] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [   10.590000] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [   10.600000] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [   10.610000] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [   10.620000] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [   10.630000] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [   10.630000] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [   10.640000] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [   10.650000] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: DE
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [   10.660000] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: DE
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [   10.660000] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: ETSI
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [   10.670000] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [   10.680000] cfg80211:   (2400000 KHz - 2483000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [   10.680000] cfg80211:   (5150000 KHz - 5350000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [   10.690000] cfg80211:   (5470000 KHz - 5725000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 3000 mBm), (N/A)
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [   10.700000] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 65880000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm), (N/A)
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [   11.070000] device br0 left promiscuous mode
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [   11.730000] device vlan2 entered promiscuous mode
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [   11.880000] device vlan2 left promiscuous mode
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [   11.920000] warning: `proftpd' uses 32-bit capabilities (legacy support in use)
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [   22.170000] nf_conntrack: automatic helper assignment is deprecated and it will be removed soon. Use the iptables CT target to attach helpers instead.
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [   25.440000] br0: port 1(vlan1) entered forwarding state
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [   43.290000] device vlan2 entered promiscuous mode
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [   43.320000] device vlan2 left promiscuous mode
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [   76.730000] device vlan2 entered promiscuous mode
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [   76.760000] device vlan2 left promiscuous mode
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [  110.180000] device vlan2 entered promiscuous mode
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [  110.210000] device vlan2 left promiscuous mode
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [  143.630000] device vlan2 entered promiscuous mode
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [  143.660000] device vlan2 left promiscuous mode
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [  177.080000] device vlan2 entered promiscuous mode
Jan  1 00:03:06 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [  177.110000] device vlan2 left promiscuous mode
Jan  1 00:03:07 DD-WRT user.info : dnsmasq : dnsmasq daemon successfully stopped
Jan  1 00:03:07 DD-WRT user.info : telnetd : telnet daemon successfully stopped
Jan  1 00:03:07 DD-WRT user.info : pptpd : pptp daemon successfully stoped
Jan  1 00:03:07 DD-WRT user.info : pptpd : pptp daemon successfully stoped
Jan  1 00:03:07 DD-WRT user.info : telnetd : telnet daemon successfully started
Jan  1 00:03:07 DD-WRT user.info : dnsmasq : dnsmasq daemon successfully started
Jan  1 00:03:08 DD-WRT user.info : klogd : kernel log daemon successfully stopped
Jan  1 00:03:08 DD-WRT kern.notice kernel: klogd: exiting
Jan  1 00:03:08 DD-WRT user.info : syslogd : syslog daemon successfully stopped
Jan  1 01:03:08 DD-WRT syslog.info syslogd exiting
Jan  1 01:03:08 DD-WRT syslog.info syslogd started: BusyBox v1.22.1
Jan  1 00:03:08 DD-WRT kern.notice kernel: klogd started: BusyBox v1.22.1 (2014-12-22 03:48:38 CET)
Jan  1 00:03:08 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[1881]: OpenVPN 2.3.6 mips-unknown-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [MH] [IPv6] built on Dec 22 2014
Jan  1 00:03:08 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[1881]: library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1j 15 Oct 2014, LZO 2.08
Jan  1 00:03:08 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[1881]: MANAGEMENT: TCP Socket listening on [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:14
Jan  1 00:03:08 DD-WRT daemon.warn openvpn[1881]: NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
Jan  1 00:03:09 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[1881]: Diffie-Hellman initialized with 1024 bit key
Jan  1 00:03:09 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[1881]: Socket Buffers: R=[87380->131072] S=[16384->131072]
Jan  1 00:03:09 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[1881]: TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Jan  1 00:03:09 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[1881]: TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Jan  1 00:03:09 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[1881]: do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=1, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Jan  1 00:03:09 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[1881]: /sbin/ifconfig tun0 10.20.30.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 mtu 1500 broadcast 10.20.30.255
Jan  1 00:03:09 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[1894]: Listening for incoming TCP connection on [undef]
Jan  1 00:03:09 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[1894]: TCPv4_SERVER link local (bound): [undef]
Jan  1 00:03:09 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[1894]: TCPv4_SERVER link remote: [undef]
Jan  1 00:03:09 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[1894]: MULTI: multi_init called, r=256 v=256
Jan  1 00:03:09 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[1894]: IFCONFIG POOL: base=10.20.30.2 size=252, ipv6=0
Jan  1 00:03:09 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[1894]: IFCONFIG POOL LIST
Jan  1 00:03:09 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[1894]: MULTI: TCP INIT maxclients=1024 maxevents=1028
Jan  1 00:03:09 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[1894]: Initialization Sequence Completed
Jan  1 00:03:23 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [  210.530000] device vlan2 entered promiscuous mode
Jan  1 00:03:23 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [  210.560000] device vlan2 left promiscuous mode
Jan  1 00:03:23 DD-WRT user.info : pppd : PPP daemon successfully stopped
Jan  1 00:03:25 DD-WRT user.info : pppd : PPP daemon hanging, send SIGKILL
Jan  1 00:03:25 DD-WRT daemon.notice pppd[1944]: pppd 2.4.6 started by root, uid 0
Jan  1 00:03:56 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [  243.990000] device vlan2 entered promiscuous mode
Jan  1 00:03:56 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [  244.020000] device vlan2 left promiscuous mode
Jan  1 00:03:56 DD-WRT user.info : pppd : PPP daemon successfully stopped
Jan  1 00:03:56 DD-WRT daemon.info pppd[1944]: Exit.
Jan  1 00:03:56 DD-WRT daemon.notice pppd[1999]: pppd 2.4.6 started by root, uid 0
Jan  1 00:04:27 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [  275.240000] device vlan2 entered promiscuous mode
Jan  1 00:04:28 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [  275.270000] device vlan2 left promiscuous mode
Jan  1 00:04:28 DD-WRT user.info : pppd : PPP daemon successfully stopped
Jan  1 00:04:28 DD-WRT daemon.info pppd[1999]: Exit.
Jan  1 00:04:28 DD-WRT daemon.notice pppd[2075]: pppd 2.4.6 started by root, uid 0
Jan  1 00:04:59 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [  306.490000] device vlan2 entered promiscuous mode
Jan  1 00:04:59 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [  306.520000] device vlan2 left promiscuous mode
Jan  1 00:04:59 DD-WRT user.info : pppd : PPP daemon successfully stopped
Jan  1 00:04:59 DD-WRT daemon.info pppd[2075]: Exit.
Jan  1 00:04:59 DD-WRT daemon.notice pppd[2130]: pppd 2.4.6 started by root, uid 0
Jan  1 00:05:30 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [  337.740000] device vlan2 entered promiscuous mode
Jan  1 00:05:30 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [  337.800000] device vlan2 left promiscuous mode
Jan  1 00:05:30 DD-WRT user.info : pppd : PPP daemon successfully stopped
Jan  1 00:05:30 DD-WRT daemon.info pppd[2130]: Exit.
Jan  1 00:05:30 DD-WRT daemon.notice pppd[2253]: pppd 2.4.6 started by root, uid 0
Jan  1 00:05:34 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [  342.250000] xt_CT: No such helper "ddtb"
Jan  1 00:05:35 DD-WRT kern.info kernel: [  342.270000] xt_CT: No such helper "ddtb"
Jan  1 00:05:35 DD-WRT user.info : vpn modules : vpn modules successfully unloaded
Jan  1 00:05:35 DD-WRT user.info : vpn modules : nf_conntrack_proto_gre successfully loaded
Jan  1 00:05:35 DD-WRT user.info : vpn modules : nf_nat_proto_gre successfully loaded
Jan  1 00:05:35 DD-WRT user.info : vpn modules : nf_conntrack_pptp successfully loaded
Jan  1 00:05:35 DD-WRT user.info : vpn modules : nf_nat_pptp successfully loaded
Jan  1 00:05:35 DD-WRT user.info : process_monitor : Process Monitor successfully stopped
Jan  1 00:05:35 DD-WRT user.info : process_monitor successfully started
Jan  1 00:05:35 DD-WRT user.info : upnp : upnp daemon successfully stopped
Jan  1 00:05:35 DD-WRT user.info : upnp : upnp daemon successfully started
Jan  1 00:05:35 DD-WRT user.info : wland : WLAN daemon successfully stopped
Jan  1 00:05:35 DD-WRT user.info : wland : WLAN daemon successfully started
Jan  1 00:05:35 DD-WRT user.info : WAN is up. IP: 100.66.137.238
Jan  1 00:05:35 DD-WRT user.info : openvpnserver : OpenVPN daemon (Server) successfully stopped
Jan  1 00:05:35 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[1894]: Closing TUN/TAP interface
Jan  1 00:05:35 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[1894]: /sbin/ifconfig tun0 0.0.0.0
Jan  1 00:05:35 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[1894]: SIGTERM[hard,] received, process exiting
Jan  1 00:05:35 DD-WRT user.info : openvpn : OpenVPN daemon (Server) starting/restarting...
Jan  1 00:05:35 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[2406]: OpenVPN 2.3.6 mips-unknown-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [MH] [IPv6] built on Dec 22 2014
Jan  1 00:05:35 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[2406]: library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1j 15 Oct 2014, LZO 2.08
Jan  1 00:05:35 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[2406]: MANAGEMENT: TCP Socket listening on [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:14
Jan  1 00:05:35 DD-WRT daemon.warn openvpn[2406]: NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
Jan  1 00:05:35 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[2406]: Diffie-Hellman initialized with 1024 bit key
Jan  1 00:05:35 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[2406]: Socket Buffers: R=[87380->131072] S=[16384->131072]
Jan  1 00:05:35 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[2406]: TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Jan  1 00:05:35 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[2406]: TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Jan  1 00:05:35 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[2406]: do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=1, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Jan  1 00:05:35 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[2406]: /sbin/ifconfig tun0 10.20.30.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 mtu 1500 broadcast 10.20.30.255
Jan  1 00:05:35 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[2416]: Listening for incoming TCP connection on [undef]
Jan  1 00:05:35 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[2416]: TCPv4_SERVER link local (bound): [undef]
Jan  1 00:05:35 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[2416]: TCPv4_SERVER link remote: [undef]
Jan  1 00:05:35 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[2416]: MULTI: multi_init called, r=256 v=256
Jan  1 00:05:35 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[2416]: IFCONFIG POOL: base=10.20.30.2 size=252, ipv6=0
Jan  1 00:05:35 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[2416]: IFCONFIG POOL LIST
Jan  1 00:05:35 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[2416]: MULTI: TCP INIT maxclients=1024 maxevents=1028
Jan  1 00:05:35 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[2416]: Initialization Sequence Completed
Dec 14 13:57:15 DD-WRT user.info : cron : cron daemon successfully stopped
Dec 14 13:57:16 DD-WRT daemon.debug process_monitor[2381]: Restarting cron  (time sync change)
Dec 14 13:57:16 DD-WRT daemon.debug process_monitor[2381]: We need to re-update after 3600 seconds
Dec 14 13:57:16 DD-WRT daemon.info process_monitor[2381]: set timer: 3600 seconds, callback: ntp_main()
Dec 14 13:57:16 DD-WRT user.info : cron : cron daemon successfully started
Dec 14 13:57:16 DD-WRT cron.info cron[2424]: (CRON) STARTUP (fork ok)
Dec 14 13:57:16 DD-WRT cron.info cron[2424]: (crontabs) ORPHAN (no passwd entry)
Dec 14 13:57:28 DD-WRT user.debug : ttraff: data collection started
Dec 14 13:57:41 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[2416]: TCP connection established with [AF_INET]192.168.1.119:35725
Dec 14 13:57:42 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[2416]: 192.168.1.119:35725 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]192.168.1.119:35725, sid=6f46ba88 329bc868
Dec 14 13:57:42 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[2416]: 192.168.1.119:35725 VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=US, ST=CA, L=SanFrancisco, O=OpenVPN, OU=changeme, CN=changeme, name=changeme, emailAddress=mail@host.domain
Dec 14 13:57:42 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[2416]: 192.168.1.119:35725 VERIFY OK: depth=0, C=US, ST=CA, L=SanFrancisco, O=OpenVPN, OU=changeme, CN=changeme, name=changeme, emailAddress=mail@host.domain
Dec 14 13:57:43 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[2416]: 192.168.1.119:35725 NOTE: --mute triggered...
Dec 14 13:57:43 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[2416]: 192.168.1.119:35725 5 variation(s) on previous 3 message(s) suppressed by --mute
Dec 14 13:57:43 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[2416]: 192.168.1.119:35725 [changeme] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]192.168.1.119:35725
Dec 14 13:57:43 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[2416]: changeme/192.168.1.119:35725 MULTI_sva: pool returned IPv4=10.20.30.2, IPv6=(Not enabled)
Dec 14 13:57:43 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[2416]: changeme/192.168.1.119:35725 OPTIONS IMPORT: reading client specific options from: /tmp/openvpn_cc_5fb53209d375ff68f805e64c26822d3b.tmp
Dec 14 13:57:43 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[2416]: changeme/192.168.1.119:35725 MULTI: Learn: 10.20.30.2 -> changeme/192.168.1.119:35725
Dec 14 13:57:43 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[2416]: changeme/192.168.1.119:35725 MULTI: primary virtual IP for changeme/192.168.1.119:35725: 10.20.30.2
Dec 14 13:57:45 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[2416]: changeme/192.168.1.119:35725 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REQUEST'
Dec 14 13:57:45 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[2416]: changeme/192.168.1.119:35725 send_push_reply(): safe_cap=940
Dec 14 13:57:45 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[2416]: changeme/192.168.1.119:35725 SENT CONTROL [changeme]: 'PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway def1,route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0,dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8,redirect-gateway def1,route-gateway 10.20.30.1,topology subnet,ping 10,ping-
Dec 14 13:58:03 DD-WRT daemon.err openvpn[2416]: changeme/192.168.1.119:35725 Connection reset, restarting [-1]
Dec 14 13:58:03 DD-WRT daemon.notice openvpn[2416]: changeme/192.168.1.119:35725 SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, client-instance restarting
```

I tried both UDP and TCP, but nothing changed.
Any help is appreciated, I am investigating more than a week, but I have no idea what is the problem.

Comment: Does your server log show a connection attempt ? Please add your VPN server log to your question.

Comment: Server log attached.

Comment: You can add a new command to your server config: `log /etc/openvpn/server.log` this will filter your server log to a separate file.  You can also add: `verb 4` to increase the details (temporarily) - FYI: your server log does **not** show a **remote client connection** only a connection from `192.168.1.119`

Comment: I presume your `remote 443` line has a `FQDN server-name` inserted as well ? (you **not** need to tell me what it is just that there is one)

Comment: Yes, debuged. The problem is that my isp gave me a natted IP, I contacted it and asked a public ip.

Answer (score 0):

As this has been solved but an answer has not been added I reread this question and wasted my time .. So I have added the actual solution provided by `user:roll` .. see here:

> Yes, debuged. The problem is that my isp gave me a natted IP, I contacted it and asked a public ip. – roll Dec 16 '15 at 6:49